# For what value of $k$ does the linear system have a unique/infinite/no solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

By using Guass-Jordan or Guass Elimination, I have to find the values of $k$ for which the following system of linear equations have a unique solution, infinite solutions and no solution.
\begin{align}
x+y+kz &= 1\\
x+ky+z &= 1\\
kx+y+z &= -2
\end{align}
I have tried to row reduce it but I am completely stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: Add your attempts and point out at which step did you get stuck? You are on the right way to row reduce it.

Comment: The determinant is $3k-k^3-2=-(k-1)^2(k+2)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have to do it using Row Reduction.

Comment: The determinant still might help you do the row reduction...

Comment: "Gauss", not "Guass"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it without the rank and determinant of the matrix. Just do the row reduction and you get
\begin{align}
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & 1 & k & 1 \\
 1 & k & 1 & 1 \\
 k & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)&\to 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & 1 & k & 1 \\
 0 & k-1 & 1-k & 0 \\
 0 & 1-k & 1-k^2 & -2-k \\
\end{array}
\right)\\&\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & 1 & k & 1 \\
 0 & k-1 & 1-k & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2-k-k^2 & -2-k \\
\end{array}
\right)\\&\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & 1 & k & 1 \\
 0 & -(1-k) & 1-k & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & (2+k)(1-k) & -(2+k) \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

Now consider the last line.

If $k=1$ you have to interpret the last line as $0=-3$, which is a contradiction. Hence the system has no solution.

If $k=-2$ you get the system
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
 0 & -3 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which has infinite many solutions. You can add a variable $z=s$ to your system and use further the Gauss-elimination
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
 0 & -3 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & s \\
\end{array}
\right)\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1+s \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & s \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & s \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
You get as the set of solutions $\mathbb L=\{(1+s,s,s)~:~s\in\mathbb R\}$.

If $k\notin\{1,-2\}$ you can divide the middle line by $k-1\neq 0$ the last line by $(2+k)(1-k)\neq 0$ and use further the Gauss-eliminination. Hence
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & 1 & k & 1 \\
 0 & -(1-k) & 1-k & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & (2+k)(1-k) & -(2+k) \\
\end{array}
\right)\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{k-1} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{k-1} \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
You get the unique solution $x=0$ and $y=z=\frac1{k-1}$ .

Answer (score 0):

Cramer's theorem: the system has one and only one solution if and only if the matrix of coefficients has a non zero determinant

$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 1 & 1 & k \\
 1 & k & 1 \\
 k & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

$\det A= -k^3+3 k-2=-(k-1)^2 (k+2)$

If $k\ne 1 \land k\ne -2$ the system has one and only one solutions

If the determinant is zero we have to look at the complete matrix, adding the column of the RHSs

If $k=1$ the complete matrix is

$
A|B=\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

In this case $\text{rank} A=1$ while $\text{rank}A|B=2$ thus the system is impossible

If $k=-2$ the matrix is

$
A|B=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
 1 & -2 & 1 & 1 \\
 -2 & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

$\text{rank} A=\text{rank}A|B=2$ the system is indeterminate. Has infinite solutions which can be found solving

$\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x+y = 1+2z\\
x-2y = 1-z
\end{array}\right.$

solutions are

$x=1+u;\;y=u;\;z=u\;\forall u\in\mathbb{R}$